# Windows 10 restarts, internet connection lost when downloading big file

Tags: windows-10, internet, download

For my work and studies, I sometimes have to download big data sets. I download these with a torrent file and qBittorrent. My desktop has a weird problem if these files are bigger than 5 GB (this is an estimation). These consist of:

1. The computer slowing down to the point where moving the cursor has severe lag for example.
2. An eventual, automatic restart of the system.
3. The internet connection being lost. After restarting, I have to reset my modem and router. This goes for everyone in the house and not just me.

These occur most when downloading a Torrent. This also happened when downloading a larger game with Steam for example. I have no trouble with online multiplayer however. 
I have tried to put a limit on download speed and using a different client for torrent files. This hasn't improved the situation.

**My set-up**

1. Windows 10 Enterprise, 64-bit
2. Intel i3-7100 3.90GHz processor
3. 8GB of RAM
4. Fatal1ty Z170 Gaming K4 motherboard with Killer E2400 Gigabit LAN controller

**My internet connection:**

1. I have a contract for 200 Mbps
2. Speedtest: 12 ping, 96.31 Mbps down, 19.46 Mbps
3. My PC is connected with LAN to the router, which is connected to the modem.

If more info is needed, please let me know.

**My question:** How do I download big files without my system rebooting and my internet connection going down and what might be the cause?

Comment: What means "most"? This is just when downloading through torrent or with other software as well? Which torrent do you use? Can you copy big files to the same destination without a problem? Can you download big files for example from an FTP server through the browser or an FTP client without a problem?

Comment: @Albin In this case 'most' is a torrent client. I also experience this with downloading larger games through Steam for example. I will post results after trying FTP

Comment: I don't know steam. But I assume you go on a website click an a link and the the browser asks you where you want to save the file. Or does the download on steam involve some other software then the browser or browser plug-ins that have to be installed before using the site?!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a start of answer about your modem going down when you use Torrent.

Peer-to-peer protocols like Torrent may create a very big amount of connexions (hundreds of connexions for example, to hundreds of peers your computer is downloading or uploading data with), you can see them a small data tubes between peers and your computer.

Modems have a maximum amount of concurrent connexions supported. Once reached, computers in your home can not create more connections toward the Internet, and can not reach any website until you stop your peer-to-peer software. A stable modem should simply act like this, but a buggy modem may mis-behave when the concurrent connexion limit is reached.

For this specific issue, you can have a look into qTorrent settings to see if it accepts a limitation on concurrent connexions it opens.

Comment: Thanks! I just decreased the amount of connections and will get back to you with results

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I tried several parameters for allowed connections. My computer still starts to lag and restarts. After that the internet goes down also and stays that way until a restart of the router and modem. Stopping the software doesn't restore either Wi-Fi or LAN connection